# Installing pods results in a aggregate target instead of framework target

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I am forking a project(which has a vendored xcframework) and adding a podspec to it because it does not support cocoapods. I add the spec on a public repo, add it as a source in a test project podfile and do `pod install`. But it adds the pod as a aggregate target in the pods project and I can't figure out why this is. I add a `import` statement and it says "No such module"

The podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name         = "Lightstreamer_iOS_Client"
  spec.version      = "4.3.2"
  spec.summary      = "Lightstreamer Client for iOS."
  spec.description  = <<-DESC
  "The Lightstreamer client for iOS lets you:
  
  * Connect to a Lightstreamer Server version 7.0 or greater.
  * Subscribe to items and receive real-time updates, keeping the bandwidth under control.
  * Subscribe to items and receive updates via mobile push notifications (MPN).
  * Send real-time messages to any metadata adapter.
  * Rely on automatic reconnection and subscription in case of network glitches."
                  DESC

  spec.homepage     = "http://www.lightstreamer.com"
  spec.documentation_url  = "https://lightstreamer.com/api/ls-ios-client/4.3.2/"
  spec.license      = {
    :type => "Lightstreamer Software License Agreement",
    :file => "Lightstreamer Software License Agreement.txt"
  }
  spec.author             = { "Lightstreamer": "support@lightstreamer.com" }
  spec.social_media_url   = "https://twitter.com/lightstreamer"
  spec.platform     = :ios
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  spec.source       = { :http => "https://www.lightstreamer.com/repo/cocoapods/ls-ios-client/#{spec.version.to_s}/ls-ios-client-#{spec.version.to_s}.zip" }
  spec.source_files = '**/*.h'
  spec.preserve_paths = '**/*.*'
  spec.vendored_framework = 'Lightstreamer_iOS_Client.xcframework'
  spec.frameworks = "Security", "SystemConfiguration"
  spec.libraries = "iconv"
  spec.requires_arc = true
end
```

The podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/developerOnjoyride/specsrepo.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'testLSPod' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Lightstreamer_iOS_Client', :git => 'https://github.com/developerOnjoyride/Lightstreamer_iOS_Client', :branch => 'CocoapodsSupport'

end
```